# Handling SIGSEGV with recover?

Tags: go

The [signal package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) states:

> Synchronous signals are signals triggered by errors in program
>   execution: SIGBUS, SIGFPE, and SIGSEGV. These are only considered
>   synchronous when caused by program execution, not when sent using
>   os.Process.Kill or the kill program or some similar mechanism. In
>   general, except as discussed below, Go programs will convert a
>   synchronous signal into a run-time panic.

However, it seems `recover()` is not catching this.

Program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"

    "log"
)

func seeAnotherDay() {
    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            err := fmt.Errorf("recover panic: panic call")
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }()
    panic("oops")
}

func notSoMuch() {
    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            err := fmt.Errorf("recover panic: sigseg")
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }()
    b := make([]byte, 1)
    log.Println("access some memory")
    foo := (*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0])) + uintptr(9999999999999999)))
    fmt.Print(*foo + 1)
}

func main() {
    seeAnotherDay()
    notSoMuch()
}
```

Output:

```
2017/04/04 12:13:16 recover panic: panic call
2017/04/04 12:13:16 access some memory
unexpected fault address 0xb01dfacedebac1e
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0x108aa8a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x10b5807, 0x5)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95 fp=0xc420043ea8 sp=0xc420043e88
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:297 +0x28c fp=0xc420043ef8 sp=0xc420043ea8
main.notSoMuch()
        /Users/kbrandt/src/sigseg/main.go:32 +0xca fp=0xc420043f78 sp=0xc420043ef8
main.main()
        /Users/kbrandt/src/sigseg/main.go:37 +0x25 fp=0xc420043f88 sp=0xc420043f78
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x20a fp=0xc420043fe0 sp=0xc420043f88
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc420043fe8 sp=0xc420043fe0
exit status 2
```

Is there any way I could handle SIGSEGV in a way localized to certain parts of the code?

Comment: In terms of "Why would you want to do this, this seems nutso" is that in my system users can create templates. And I want to protect the main runtime from any errors generated while rendering templates. The real world issue is on github [here](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/2054).

Comment: Chatting with people in Gopher slack the idea seems to be that sigsegv puts the program in an undefined state and can't be recovered from safely.

Comment: You can't recover from a `fatal error`, it's not a `panic`

Comment: So your code does not recover, because your example don't panic: https://play.golang.org/p/XtfxlLzr51

Comment: @JimB Does that mean the quoted documentation in os/signal is wrong and it is not converted to panic? Or am not interpreting the documentation incorrectly?

Comment: @KyleBrandt: it can be converted to a panic, but in this case with "unexpected fault address" the runtime doesn't know how to proceed. https://play.golang.org/p/dhRRq2--64

Comment: @KyleBrandt Yes, the documentation in that section appears to be incomplete and should be updated.  Under some conditions SIGBUS and SIGSEGV are converted to fatal errors instead of panics.  See sigpanic function in runtime/signal_unix.go for the specific cases. 
 https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/signal_unix.go#L358-L413  Note that these cases can be overridden by applying debug.SetPanicOnFault as noted below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you will want to use [debug.SetPanicOnFault](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetPanicOnFault) to convert faults at an unexpected (non-nil) address into panics from which you can recover.  From the docs:

> SetPanicOnFault controls the runtime's behavior when a program faults at an unexpected (non-nil) address. Such faults are typically caused by bugs such as runtime memory corruption, so the default response is to crash the program. Programs working with memory-mapped files or unsafe manipulation of memory may cause faults at non-nil addresses in less dramatic situations; SetPanicOnFault allows such programs to request that the runtime trigger only a panic, not a crash. SetPanicOnFault applies only to the current goroutine. It returns the previous setting.

For the localization of the impact, note that SetPanicOnFault is set at the goroutine level, so a single goroutine can deal with known unsafe access.

Comment: This would be inappropriate for the scenario @KyleBrandt is describing, though. It does not "protect the main runtime from any errors generated [in other goroutines]". As the documentation above indicates, it allows you to prevent the runtime from exiting in situations where you know that the faults you're triggering are benign. With code that the user has provided, you know nothing, and it is quite possible that a fault it generates has corrupted the memory of the process and left it in an undefined state, where continued execution in _any_ goroutine could go haywire.

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter a sigsegv, you're really in an all-bets-are-off situation with regards to the program state. The only generally safe thing to do is to stop everything, and possibly have the system dump your memory to file for debugging, which is what Go does. There isn't really any way to "protect the main runtime" in this situation.

If you have a runtime that is running code that is untrusted or unsafe, you really should isolate it into a separate process instead. And if *you* are the one running the code received from the users (rather than the users themselves), this process should most definitely be sandboxed.

So my advice is, do either of the following:

1. Let it crash and let the user handle it from there. The user writing code causing a sigsegv in Go normally requires more or less active attempts of shooting in the direction of one's foot, so it should be rare and arguably filed under things they are doing at their own risk anyway.
2. Separate it into a supervisor process and an "untrusted/unsafe" child process, where the supervisor picks up improper exit conditions from the child process and reports them appropriately.